# No database on the company servers, alternatives to save data?

Tags: database

I've been struggling with this issue for a while. Our company servers lack any sort of database, i.e. no MySQL, MongoDB, etc in sight.

Since we can't install any for reasons beyond the scope of this question, I was wondering if there was any alternative to that that I could use to save data from a form. (We collect prospect data through a form on our site which then sends this data in the form of an email and is plugged in our internal database through email2DB...)

Comment: You could use hosted MySQL outside of the company, assuming that the firewall allows it. You'll need a good internet connection as well, to (somewhat) reduce the inevitable latency introduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a library like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

You could also use indexed files like [Gdbm](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/)

However, you should think about backup strategies. Perhaps [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) should be a concern (and using textual or portable data formats like XDR, ASN1, JSON, YAML, ...).

But you might also try to discuss with managers to install e.g. a MySQL server on a machine. You don't need a dedicated hardware for that, it can run (at least for development and test) on a machine used for some other things.

Comment: +1 for SQLite

Did some reading and it seems that its self-contained nature makes it real easy to paliate such issues. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

textfile?:)
or perhaps TinySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as a flat file.  Flat files work great when you are just saving things like logs, or output from a webform.  They quickly start to fail if you have any *-to-many relationships.

Do you have access to PHP?